# Segmentation Fault for OpenMP nested loop

Tags: c++, openmp

I have a program which finds similar strings from a database consists of million strings of same length `m`. The input to my program is a string of length `n` (>>> `m`). The program checks for each substring of length `m`. It is implemented in c++ and uses OpenMP, but I am getting segmentation fault for the following piece of code. The string contains only four characters `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. The program finds the similar strings and if the hamming distance is less than given value, then it counts the occurrences of each character (stores it in `ARR`)

```
           std::map<char, int> mapp = {{'A', 0}, {'B', 1}, {'C', 2}, {'D', 3}};
           int **ARR = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*)*n);
           for(int z=0; z<n; z++)
             ARR[z] = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*4);
           for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
             for(int j=0; j<4; j++) ARR[i][j] = 0; 

            vector<string> V;
            #pragma omp parallel for private(V) shared(ARR) 
            for(int i=0; i<str.length()-m-1; i++){  
              std::string substr = str.substr(i, m);
              for(int j=0; j<N; j++){  // N number of databases to search
                V = retrieve(substr);  // find similar strings
                for(int k=0; k<(int)V.size(); ++k) {
                  int hd = hamming_distance(substr, V[k]); // no. of mismatches between substr and kth element of V
                  if( h < minHD){
                    for(int l=0; l<m; l++){
                      char c = V[k][l];
                      #pragma omp critical
                      {
                        ARR[j+l][mapp.at(c)]++;
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
```

I am just wondering if there are any race conditions because of nested loop which gives seg fault. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `std::string substr = str.substr(j, m);` why is there `j` outside of inner loop?

Comment: sorry, it should be `i`

Comment: And what does `retrieve` do? Are you sure, that error is not in that function?

Comment: I am using a library which has a function that retrieves a set of strings similar to the given string. It returns a vector of strings. Yes, I am sure the error is not in that function.

Comment: ... then replace it with a dummy and make a proper [mcve] instead of keeping us guessing about where the actual error might be.

Comment: @Zulan The code has been updated